what did I drill into in my ceiling? is it ok?
https://ibb.co/dtzXXWC
https://ibb.co/fQdjNJh
I wanted to hang something from my ceiling. I thought I was all that with my stud finder. Turns out I am not. It went in fairly easily so I am guessing a vent. We don't have central air. There's a heater that we never use mounted on the wall.
Kind of older apartment complex. On first floor. There is a tenant above us. I am being "scummy" in that I just planned on filling and painting the hole when moving out. Done it before and no landlords ever noticed. Help please. Ignore it? Do something specific?

How deep did the hole end up? Duct is not a bad guess. Is there a bathroom or kitchen fan that might route this way?

@KMJ it feels empty inside (I wiggled the drill bit around). I MIGHT have felt some insulation but nothing was on the bit when I pulled it out. Bathroom fan going this way seems very unlikely. Do ceiling insulation sheets with a like-metal face exist? Maybe that's what it is?

There is foam insulation with a thin aluminum film on it. If it's that, you might find this sort of metal anywhere you drill.
